# display top 10 high scores in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

am integrated openfeint succesfuly its for global score, i want local top 10 high score display in cocos2d game

Anyone has a basic tutorial for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSArray to keep the scores. And save/load it using NSUserDefaults

If you have a fixed number of levels - use NSArray to keep. When array values are changed:

```
-(void) saveScore
{
    NSUserDefaults *settings = [NSUserDefaults standartUserDefaults];
    [settings setObject: myScoreArray forKey:@"my scores"];
    [settings synchronize];
}
```

To load your array:

```
-(void) loadScores
{
    NSUserDefaults *settings = [NSUserDefaults standartUserDefaults];
    myScoreArray = [settings objectForKey:@"my scores"];
    //also check if myScoreArray in nil - first launch
}
```